# SQL age range selection but making an exception

Tags: mysql, date

Today I'm stucked in a very difficult case. I made a sql query to pick an age range betwen 18 years and 30 years, but according to the rules of a competition for which I make this script it is necessary to allow an exdeptie for two members who are under the age of 18.

So far I tried to select ages with this query but I do not know how I could enter this exception.

Here is the query without the exception part:

```
SELECT * 
FROM competitors 
WHERE BIRTHDATE <= NOW() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR AND BIRTHDATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 YEAR
```

Comment: If you don't want to recode every time a new exception comes along consider adding an exceptions table.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `or` condition:

```
WHERE BIRTHDATE <= NOW() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR AND BIRTHDATE > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 YEAR
OR member_id IN (123, 456)
```